# C# dependency injection with container when having List<T> as coupling

Tags: c#, list, dependency-injection

I have a class `Player` that contains a `List<ICoordinate>`. I want to apply dependency injection with a container to avoid having a hard coupling between both classes. `ICoordinate` is registered with Microsoft's container. I can create an instance through the container without any problems, but when I expect a `List<ICoordinate>` in the constructor of `Player`, I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Globals.Interfaces.ICoordinate]' while attempting to activate 'Globals.Entities.Player'

What am I doing wrong? Or what is the 'professional way to have DI with `List<T>`?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

1 instance works, but a List gives the error.

Comment: Please share the actual code instead of images of it.

Comment: Did you try using `IEnumerable<ICoordinate>` instead of a list?

Comment: Yes IEnumerable<ICoordinate> does work indeed. I guess i can convert it to a list. Tank you! 

Is using IEnumerable<T> the way to go for using DI with  container and having Lists or other collections? @Eldar?

Comment: Yes, the default way is, but there are other options too,  you can register a service that has a method that returns a list of services (factory service). But you should be aware that if you want to inject a concrete class (Such as List<T>) you need to register it as a concrete class which is against the DI principle.

Comment: [I downvoted because an image of your code is not helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Answer (score 0):

Change the constructor parameter type to `IEnumerable<ICoordinate>`: This is generally a good practice as it promotes loose coupling and allows for easier testing and substitution of dependencies.

```cs
public Player(IEnumerable<ICoordinate> coordinates)
{
    // Use the coordinates as needed
}
```